# String Escaping With $ Interpolation and @ Encoding

Tags: c#, string-interpolation, html-escape-characters

I am trying to escape a " character within an interpolated string block like below.

```
var name = "Mr. Roguers";
var htmlEmail = $@"
    <p>Dear {name},</p>
    <p>Please click this awesome <a href=\"google.com\">link.</a></p>
";
Console.WriteLine(htmlEmail);
```

I've looked in a lot of places, can anyone provide some direction or a solution to escape this with using the $ and @. I want my code to be multi-lined like this so that it is clear to read, which is why I have the @ symbol. I also would like to use the $ string interpolation.

This code does not compile using .NET Core 2.2

I am testing it in Visual Studio in my own solution and also this trivial example I tested it on https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: The only place you need to look into is [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) on verbatim strings. `Only a quote escape sequence ("") is not interpreted literally; it produces a single quotation mark. Additionally, in case of a verbatim interpolated string brace escape sequences ({{ and }}) are not interpreted literally; they produce single brace characters. `

Comment: Yup, the only thing I saw when I looked was for the curly brackets {{ }}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using @, a double quote inside a string is to be represented as `""`:

```
var htmlEmail = $@"
    <p>Dear {name},</p>
    <p>Please click this awesome <a href=""google.com"">link.</a></p>
";
```

.NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fESnd1

**Explanation:**

The @ causes the compiler to take strings literally instead of interpreting them. With the @ linebreaks inside string literals are allowed, and the backslash `\` becomes a normal string character instead of an escape character, causing e.g. `@"\r\n"` to be a string of four characters: `\`, `r`, `\` and `n`. This made it necessary to use another way to include a double quote, which became `""`.

*Reference:* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim